# Spring MyBatis w/o Maven

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, mybatis

So I integrated MyBatis with Spring successfully(?) I think, because all my jUnit Test Methods are working correctly. I only received this error when Im trying to launch the web app locally on my tomcat server here is the stack trace:

[image: a very long stack trace]

Here's my web.xml

[image]

I can provide you with more of my codes if you want to. And yes I didn't use maven here.

UPDATE: Added a screenshot of my packaging.

[image]

UPDATE: Added library screenshot. Prolly thinking because of the version of spring?:
[image]

Comment: How do you package your application? Make sure, that all libraries are packaged.

Comment: Hi dunni, I added a screenshot of my packaging.

Comment: No, i meant, how do you create the WAR file. Maven, Gradle, Ant?

Comment: Oh sorry. Not yet packaging it. I'm just right clicking the project then run as server. @dunni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, after your descriptions the problem is, that Eclipse is not recognizing your libraries automatically (otherwise, they would have a small added icon on its main icon, which would look like the Libraries icon). The reason for this could be, that you have configured WEB-INF as source folder, which it shouldn't be (since you don't have any Java sources in it). So first i suggest to remove that configuration. Then Eclipse should pick your libraries automatically, when you deploy the application.

Comment: Ok, so I need to add the jars to my build path? I only configured the web inf as a source folder so that spring could be recognized and found. But then I'll try to do this. Thanks @dunni

Comment: Eclipse should automatically add all jars in WEB-INF/lib to the buildpath, so as soon as you remove the folder from the source folders, that should happen.

Comment: hi already removed the web inf as a source folder ran it again, it's still not loading.